# Creating thumbnail Image from video not working

Tags: php

I have code in php. This works fine in my local server . But the same code is not working in my destination remote server which is hosted in AWS .

```
<?php


$ffmpeg = "C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg";

$imagefile = "1.png";
$size = "920*440";
$getfromsecond = 44;
$cmd = "$ffmpeg -i aaa.mp4 -an -ss $getfromsecond -s $size $imagefile";

$p =system($cmd);


?>
```

My aaa.mp4  is in same folder as in the script locates .

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access your C:\ drive which is not located on your AWS server.
You need to specify your remote destination.